# How do I omit script elements from HTML using XPath in Nokogiri in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xpath, nokogiri

Say I start with everything inside the body element:

```
Nokogiri::HTML( doc ).xpath( "/html/body/node()" ).to_html
```

which contains some `<script>` and `<noscript>`. How do I get rid of these?

Comment: Are you trying to sanitize/purify your HTML?

Comment: I don't know enough about HTML to answer that, but I am trying to rewrite some command-line XSLT commands into Nokogiri, since Heroku doesn't support command-line tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to change your XPath expression to:

```
Nokogiri::HTML( doc ).xpath( "/html/body/node()[not(self::script or self::noscript)]" ).to_html
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'nokogiri'

html = <<EOT
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      <!-- dummy script !>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script><!-- dummy script !></script>
    <noscript>dummy script</noscript>
  </body>
</head>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
```

Here's the gist of it:

```
doc.at('body').search('script,noscript').remove

puts doc.to_xml

>> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
>> <html>
>> <head>
>> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
>> <script>
>>       <!-- dummy script !>
>>     </script>
>> </head>
>> <body>
>>     
>>   </body>
>> </html>
```

For simplicity, I'm using Nokogiri's ability to use CSS accessors, rather than XPath.

```
doc.at('body').search('script,noscript').remove
```

looks for the first occurrence of the `<body>` tag, then looks inside for all `<script>` and `<noscript>` tags, removing them.

The gap between the resulting `<body>` tags are the result of the carriage returns in text nodes that trailed the actual target tags.